# How can I align keys A, B, C, D exam-randomizechoices?

Tags: align, vertical-alignment, exam

I asked [this question](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=6375) and thanks to samcarter about [comment](https://topanswers.xyz/transcript?room=6421).
[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[randomize,overload]{exam-randomizechoices}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[shape=circle, draw, minimum size=1.5em, inner sep=0pt , thick] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand\choicelabel{\circled{\Alph{choice}}}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
    \settowidth{\leftmargin}{0pt}}
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{\settowidth{\leftmargin}{\circled{W}.\hskip\labelsep\hskip 0em}}
\newcommand{\correctchoicelabel}{\fbox{\thechoice}}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\correctchoicelabel}}
\usepackage[left=1.7cm,right=1.7cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \section{Questions}
    \begin{questions}
        \question What is 2+2?
        
        \begin{oneparchoices}   
        
        \choice \makebox[.2\textwidth][l]{1}
        \CorrectChoice \makebox[.2\textwidth][l]{4}
        \choice \makebox[.2\textwidth][l]{2}
        \choice \makebox[.2\textwidth][l]{3}               
    \end{oneparchoices} 
    \question What is 2+2?
            
    \begin{oneparchoices}   
        
        \choice \makebox[.2\textwidth][l]{1}
        \CorrectChoice \makebox[.2\textwidth][l]{4}
        \choice \makebox[.2\textwidth][l]{2}
        \choice \makebox[.2\textwidth][l]{3}               
    \end{oneparchoices} 
        
        \question What is the result of $y = x^3 - 3x^2 + 7x - 1$?
        
\begin{oneparchoices}   
    
    \choice \makebox[.4\textwidth][l]{some thing}
    \CorrectChoice \makebox[.4\textwidth][l]{$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$}
    \choice \makebox[.4\textwidth][l]{$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$}
    \choice \makebox[.4\textwidth][l]{$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$}               
\end{oneparchoices} 
        
    

\question What is 2+2?

\begin{choices} 
    \choice Very long text Very long text Very long text 
    \CorrectChoice Very long text Very long text Very long text 
    \choice Very long text Very long text Very long text 
    \choice Very long text Very long text Very long text           
\end{choices}  

        
    \end{questions}
    
    \subsection{Keys}
    \centering
    \printkeytable
\end{document}
```

In this case the key A, B, C, D  line in two columns like question 3, I want to align the key B (some thing) and key D (a^2 + b^2 = c^2) so that in the same line with keys C of two questions 1 and 2. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: If you are asking here, you should add that information to your existing question to avoid duplicated efforts.

Comment: What does 'Câu 101 1962 (AHSME Problems/Problem 32)' mean in the output you show there? (If it is output?)

Comment: That picture I want to show for samcarter the way I want to align. Please don't care it.

Comment: @cfr I think, I add that information about my question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `oneparchoices` is a paragraph. It only looks like a tabular because of all entries are the same width. First you need to make `\correctchoicelabel` the same width as `choicelabel`.  When doing two columns, the width includes the missing column label and whatever gap gets added between columns. Trial and error is your best bet.  Spaces at the end of a line seem to cause random variations.

Geometry it incompatible with exam class, which handles its own margins (see `\extrawidth` page 26).

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,answers]{exam}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[randomize,overload]{exam-randomizechoices}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newlength{\choicewidth}

\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{%
        \node[shape=circle, draw, minimum size=1.5em, inner sep=0pt , thick] (char) {#1};}}
\renewcommand\choicelabel{\circled{\Alph{choice}}}
\settowidth{\choicewidth}{\choicelabel}
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{\settowidth{\leftmargin}{0pt}}
\renewcommand{\choiceshook}{\setlength{\labelwidth}{\choicewidth}
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{\dimexpr \labelwidth+\labelsep}}
\newcommand{\correctchoicelabel}{\makebox[\choicewidth]{\fbox{\thechoice}}}
\CorrectChoiceEmphasis{\renewcommand{\choicelabel}{\correctchoicelabel}}
%\usepackage[left=1.7cm,right=1.7cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \section{Questions}
    \begin{questions}
        \question What is 2+2?
        
    \begin{oneparchoices}
        \choice \makebox[.2\linewidth][l]{1}%
        \CorrectChoice \makebox[.2\linewidth][l]{4}%
        \choice \makebox[.2\linewidth][l]{r}%
        \choice \makebox[.2\linewidth][l]{r}%
    \end{oneparchoices}
    
    \question What is 2+2?
            
    \begin{oneparchoices}
        \choice \makebox[.2\linewidth][l]{1}%
        \CorrectChoice \makebox[.2\linewidth][l]{4}%
        \choice \makebox[.2\linewidth][l]{2}%
        \choice \makebox[.2\linewidth][l]{3}%
    \end{oneparchoices} 
        
        \question What is the result of $y = x^3 - 3x^2 + 7x - 1$?
        
\begin{oneparchoices}
    \choice \makebox[.485\linewidth][l]{some thing}%
    \CorrectChoice \makebox[.485\linewidth][l]{$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$}%
    \choice \makebox[.485\linewidth][l]{$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$}%
    \choice \makebox[.485\linewidth][l]{$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$}%
\end{oneparchoices} 

\question What is 2+2?

\begin{choices} 
    \choice Very long text Very long text Very long text 
    \CorrectChoice Very long text Very long text Very long text 
    \choice Very long text Very long text Very long text 
    \choice Very long text Very long text Very long text           
\end{choices}  
\end{questions}
    
    \subsection{Keys}
    \centering
    \printkeytable
\end{document}
```